# JavaScript and C# Interpolation using Microsoft.JScript

Tags: c#

How can I add a C# object to JavaScript code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.JScript;
using Microsoft.JScript.Vsa;
using Microsoft.Vsa;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            program.Run();
        }

        public object Run()
        {

            VsaEngine Engine = VsaEngine.CreateEngine();

            object Result = null;
            try
            {
                //Engine.PushScriptObject(new ScriptObject());
                // C# object replace with ?
                Result = Eval.JScriptEvaluate("var a = 1; var b = c# object", Engine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
            return Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: interpolation... I don't think it means what you think it means. (I think you mean interoperability)

Answer (score 0):

Just compile your C# object into an assembly and load that assembly in your jscript code.  all the languages that .NET supports can load each other's assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp)

As they say,

"Script# brings the power and productivity of C# and .NET tools to Ajax development by compiling C# source code into regular JavaScript."